# how do i combine multiple powershell scripts in a guided install (for example with wix) but without the trail (ARP etc.)

Tags: powershell, sharepoint

I am working on a project where we need to repeat certain steps with powershell to deploy stuff. i would like to create a process/install guidance (steps supported with UI) with WIX but after the msi has finished i have an entry in programs and features. I just need it to execute the powershell and then end without registering in windows. i might be using the wrong tooling or whatever, any suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to create a program install wrapper which would install the MSI first and then call the Powershell script.

[Installers](http://unattended.sourceforge.net/installers.php)

Some of the tools that might be helpful are:

[Inno Installer](http://www.jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php)

[AutoIT](https://www.autoitscript.com/site/)

Hope this helps!